# Get device currency with Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a question about currencies. How can I get device currency based on region, location or something like this? There are cases when (for example) device language (and locale) set to English, but currency is Euro or Peso. Currently I'm using `NumberFormat` which is based on `localeCode`, but it generates errors for some regions.

For example

`country: Ukraine`,

`language: Russian`,

`currency: Russian ruble` <- wrong. Should be Ukrainian hryvna.

I don't know how, but Google Play deals with this problem :) So I think it should be also possible for other apps.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the following, it should work with Ukrainian hryvna:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

String currency = NumberFormat.simpleCurrency(locale: Platform.localeName).currencySymbol;
```

Comment: actually, this is how code looks like now. But I have bug reports from Ukraine saying that default currency is Russian Ruble...

Comment: you could add a dictionary for the few countries that don't have the correct currency

Comment: yep... This is only one solution that come to my mind :)

Comment: sorry I couldn't help more :) let me know if you need help to make the hashmap but its quite easy